# Execution failed for task ':firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  >   /home/vishnu/quest/build/firebase_admob/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:304: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  >   /home/vishnu/quest/build/firebase_admob/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:305: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.